# Can I use the Windows Ribbon UI on Windows XP? how?

Tags: windows-7, windows-installer, ribbon, windows-ribbon-framework

I understand from reading [Arik Poznanski's blog](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arik/archive/2009/09/03/windows-ribbon-for-winforms-part-1-introduction.aspx) that the [Windows Ribbon UI Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd316910%28VS.85%29.aspx) is a COM object in Windows 7, and the [WindowsRibbon wrapper](http://windowsribbon.codeplex.com) is just a .NET veneer around that, to allow the Ribbon UI to be used in Windows Forms applications.

I've been successful in implementing a Hello World Windows Form app that employs this wrapper:

[image: Windows Ribbon HEllo World]

It is running on my development machine, which is Windows7.

---

Questions:

- Will this "hello, world" application run on Vista?  XP?   Do I need to download something onto those machines in order to make that happen?
- Is there a way to specify the Windows Ribbon UI components as a pre-requisite, in an MSI installer?

Thanks

---

Browsing around I found [the documentation for UIRibbon.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd742706%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which is the DLL on Windows7 that delivers the Ribbon UI.  It lists these as minimum supported clients:

> Windows 7, Windows Vista with SP2 and Platform Update for Windows Vista

how would I check for that  in an MSI ?

Comment: For ribbon UI on XP, check out http://www.bcgsoft.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best I can tell, you are taking on a dependency that won't work on Windows XP.  This doesn't seem to be a redistributable component ( although I will admit hacking on a VM trying to see if I could transplant it into an XP machine ).

Since it isn't redistributable, I'm not sure there's any point in doing a search in MSI as you can just rely on checking the OS Major version ( Win7 ).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Ok, not available on WinXP.  What about Vista?  The doc page says it works on Vista with the "platform update."  Any ideas on that?  How would I check for that?   Also - I'm curious.  You did some hacking with XP. What happens when you run an app on XP, that depends on UIribbon.dll ? Did you try?

Comment: I only went as far as looking at it in depends and trying to see if I could get the CLSID's registered.  If you look in the source code of that CodePlex project you'll find a class file that has the CLSID guid's.   For an MSI, you write an AppSearch/RegLocator combination that searches the registry for that CLSID.

Comment: BTW, KB971644 is the platform update for Vista but it's only available through WSUS and Windows Update.  However, it has a subcombone of KB960362 (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/960362/) which is available for download ( 4 versions for vista/2008/x86/x64 )

Answer (score 1):

You are free to use a Ribbon UI wherever you like (subject to [the Ribbon license agreement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa973809); which basically asks that you don't make a half-assed version).

There are companies that created their own Ribbon controls. Some of those implementations (i.e. Microsoft's Windows Ribbon Framework) only work on Windows 7 or Windows Vista (with a download installed first).

---

If you want to check that the Windows Ribbon Framework is available on the client machine, try to create a `UIRibbonFramework` object:

```
IUIFramework* pFramework = NULL;
HRESULT hr = ::CoCreateInstance(
            CLSID_UIRibbonFramework, 
            NULL,
            CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
            IID_PPV_ARGS(&pFramework));
if (FAILED(hr))
{
  //Ribbon not available - fallback to something else
  return;
}
```